# Stabilizing plot using root locus method

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, stability

"Design a PI controller to stabilize the plant \$ G(s)= 1/(s-1)\$ using only root locus method."

Since there are two variables \$K_p\$ and \$K_i\$ ,i.e. one for proportional and one for integral, How do I even start to plot the root locus as there are 2 variables, then how do I stabilize the overall system. I know that Poles must lie on LHP, that can be solved analytically, but how do I find them from the Root locus only, any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you use Matlab/Octave/Software or are you to do that manually?

Comment: @jDAQ manually using approximated root locus

Comment: Are there more constraints to the problem, such as maximum overshoot to a unit step? Or just "stability"?

Comment: If you just want to stabilize it, you could consider just the Kp and apply root locus and get it done.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy yes only stability

Comment: @jDAQ won't Ki come into the picture?

Comment: Just try that out, apply root locus to the system and see where the (only) pole moves to. Since it has to move along the real line you should be able to stabilize it with just a proportional controller.

Comment: Draw root locus multiple times each time with a (different) fixed value for Ki; first root locus with Ki = 0, next with 0.1, next with 0.5 etc.

Comment: @AJN yes got it

Comment: @jDAQ yes worked. Thanks. And by the way, latex doesn't work in this site? I tried typing $ \frac_{1}{s-1} $ but it didn't work. Sorry i am new here and advice would be helpful

Comment: you can use double dollar signs $$ x = Ay $$ and  \\$ \$ f(\cdot)\$ to type equations, you can also click on the equation to see their latex code

Comment: What are the specifications you are looking for?